# JSF selectBooleanCheckBox does not retain value

Tags: jsf

I am new to JSF. I have a selectBooleanCheckbox on a form. with 2 command button, search and downlaod. Search will show the results ion the form itself as well as download will download an excel file.

The value of the selectBooleanCheckbox  is not retained when I click the button after clicking the search button.  At first the value is retained but for the second time the value is lost .

```
<t:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="自動車"  value="#{busRptListForm.srcVo.chkAuto}" onclick="document.getElementById('BusinessResults').submit();">
<h:commandButton id="search"  value="#{msgs['label.button.kensaku']}" action="#{busRptListForm.search}" onclick="openLoadingWindow();" />
<h:commandButton id="downloadId" value="#{msgs['label.download']}"  action="#{busRptListForm.doBusRptDownload}" ajax="true"  style="width: 75px; padding: 3px;"/>

<t:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="自動車"  value="#{busRptListForm.srcVo.chkAuto}" >
<h:commandButton id="downloadId" value="#{msgs['label.download']}"  action="#{busRptListForm.doBusRptDownload}"  style="width: 75px; padding: 3px;"/>
<h:commandButton id="search"  value="#{msgs['label.button.kensaku']}" action="#{busRptListForm.search}" onclick="openLoadingWindow();" />
```

The check boxes values are retained when I directly click the download button but if I press the search button first and on the same search criteria I try to press the download button at that time it loses the value of the checkbox but all other selectboxes and textboxes values are retained.

If I call a javascript function on the download button which opens the wait dialog box then this problem does not occur but I don't want to call the javascript wait dialogbox

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow, please read this guide to asking a good question: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/  You should expect this question to be flagged for closure due to being low quality unless you edit your question add some code.

Comment: You can edit your question via the edit button. And read [ask] and [mcve] and take the [tour] again. And have you taken over an existing project or starting from scratch?

Comment: What does `0 down vote favorite` mean here? Have you just copy+pasted this question from somewhere?